# I am getting "Unable to Parse Line" while trying to download the Excel file using AutoIT

Tags: excel, selenium, autoit

I am getting "Unable to Parse Line" while trying to download the Excel file using AutoIT. Please find the attached screen shot for the same. Find the below code I have used.

```
;Exact location of WebSite from where we would like to download the file.We are 
reading url from commandline
$URL ="https://www.700creditsolution.com/dasdetail.aspx"

;Local address to which we would like to download the file
$filename = "C:\Users\Umamaheshwar\Downloads\scenario.xls"
WinActivate("[700CreditSolution]", "Export to Excel")
InetGet ($URL, $filename , 1, 0)
<span style="font-family: Times New Roman;"><span style="white-space: normal;">
</span></span>
```

I am tagging this Question in Webdriver forum, because people who use AutoIT, but may not be the members in AutoIt forum.

Please help me out on this issue. Help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Why is there HTML (`<span>...</span>`) in your AutoIt code?

Answer (score 0):

Before compiling any code in autoit you should run a

```
SyntaxCheck by pressing CTRL+F5
```

It will check the syntax of your code and alert you if there are problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have verified the syntax check and tried to download the file, but it is downloading the Login page content to Excel file. please help me to complete this issue

Comment: Does this website require you to log in in order to download the spreadsheet? If so, you'll have to do more than a simple HTTP GET because the web server won't give you the same content that you have access to in the browser (after you've authenticated). Different sites do it differently, but they're probably relying on cookies or server-side sessions and not just your IP address. If you're doing it with selenium, you've got a much better chance of getting it to work, but I don't know why you'd need AutoIt __and__ Selenium. Selenium ought to be sufficient.

Comment: First, your link is probably wrong. When you download it manually , you probably click on a link. Copy that link and put it in $URL.
If your site requires login, you can try https://myusername:mypassword@700creditsolution.com/path_to_my_download_file.xls

Comment: replace myusername, mypassword and path_to_my_download_file.xls with real data.

Comment: If none of above works, I suggest you use IE.au3 UDF because using WinHTTP.au3 on aspx pages can be tricky for a starter.